# Regex for matching time format

Tags: c#, regex-group

I am looking to match the following time format

```
[hours]:[minutes]:[seconds]
[minutes]:[seconds]
[total_seconds]
```

My attempt was

```
([0-9]{1,2}:)?([0-9]{1,2}:)?([0-9]+)
```

But it fails for `[minutes]:[seconds]`, `23:45` matches `[hours]:[minutes]:[seconds]` with minutes as empty.

Comment: your attempt will also match `99:99:999999999999999999999999999999999999` and `12341234123412341234123412341234`

Comment: I am fine with it, I don't expect the data to be wrong.

Comment: What about [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__)?

Comment: @JimMischel, this looks promising, I did not know it is possible to pass multiple formats (thanks, I learnt something new). I am not sure though if there is a format for just `total_seconds` `ss` maybe limited to max of 60. Anyway let me try it.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```py
regex=r"(^\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$)|(^\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$)|(^\d+$)"
```